# Put a view on Storyboard above all others

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, view

I have a ViewController file and in this ViewController file, I create programmatically a view which it takes all the available place on the window.

Now, I want to make a view with the Storyboard. I put this view (in my case a button) on my Storyboard.

And when I launch my application, I cannot see my button because it is under the view which I created before programmatically.

Is this possible to have my Storyboard view above the other view ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you provide lines of code where you add your view in ViewController and add it to view. Looks like you use addSubview method.

Comment: In method are you adding your button view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Looks like you use `addSubview` method. 
The problem that you encountered is that views added in such way overlay the existed views.

You can either bring button to front with `bringSubviewToFront` or use `insertSubview:belowSubview` and `insertSubview:aboveSubview` to fix such issues. In both cases you'll need your button stored in property.

Answer (score 1):

It sort of depends on your view hierarchy setup.

I'm assuming this:

```
A - View controller view
  | B - Your button 
  | C - Programmatically added fullscreen view
```

In the above case you could do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.button];
}
```

Point is `bringSubviewToFront:` moves a subview to the top of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

So you will have to create an outlet for the button (connect the button in storyboard to the name given to it in your .swift file) Once you have added the view programmatically, you just have to do

`self.view.bringSubviewToFront(button)`

Assuming that button is the name of the outlet. This line will be added after adding the view programatically.